# Functional way to update an object based on flags

Tags: scala, functional-programming

suppose you are writing a class that normalizes strings.  That class has a number of configuration flags.  For example:

```
   val makeLowerCase: Boolean = true
   val removeVowels: Boolean = false
   val dropFirstCharacter: Boolean = true
```

If I were writing mutable code, I would write the following for the `normalize` method.

```
def normalize(string: String) = {
  var s = string

  if (makeLowerCase) {
    s = s.toLowerCase
  }

  if (removeVowels) {
    s = s.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "")
  }

  if (dropFirstCharacter) {
    s = s.drop(1)
  }

  s
}
```

Is there a clean and easy way of writing these without mutation?  Nested conditionals becomes nasty fast.  I could create a list of `String=>String` lambdas, filter it based on the configuration, and then fold the string through it, but I hope there is something easier.

Comment: Avoiding mutation within a small function is much less important than readability.  As long as your function produces no external side-effects you shouldn't worry about it much.  It's impossible to sort efficiently without mutation, for example, but as long as you mutate a copy no-one outside the function can tell the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) `|>` operator or have a similar one defined in your utility classes you can do this:

```
case class N(
  makeLowerCase: Boolean = true,
  removeVowels: Boolean = false,
  dropFirstCharacter: Boolean = true) {

  def normalize(string: String) = (
    string 
      |> (s => if (makeLowerCase) s.toLowerCase else s) 
      |> (s => if (removeVowels) s.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "") else s) 
      |> (s => if (dropFirstCharacter) s.drop(1) else s) 
  )

}

N(removeVowels=true).normalize("DDABCUI")
// res1: String = dbc
```

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is to define your own method:

```
class ConditionalMapper[A](a: A) {
  def changeCheck(p: A => Boolean)(f: A => A) = if (p(a)) f(a) else a
  def changeIf(b: Boolean)(f: A => A) = if (b) f(a) else a
}
implicit def conditionally_change_anything[A](a: A) = new ConditionalMapper(a)
```

Now you chain these things together and write:

```
class Normer(makeLC: Boolean, remVowel: Boolean, dropFirst: Boolean) {
  def normalize(s: String) = {
    s.changeIf(makeLC)   { _.toLowerCase }
     .changeIf(remVowel) { _.replaceAll("[aeiou]","") }
     .changeIf(dropFirst){ _.substring(1) }
  }
}
```

Which gives you:

```
scala> val norm = new Normer(true,false,true)
norm: Normer = Normer@2098746b

scala> norm.normalize("The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog")
res1: String = he quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

That said, the mutable solution is not bad either--just keep it to a small block and you'll be fine.  It's mostly a problem when you let mutability escape into the wild.  (Where "the wild" means "outside your method, or inside any method more than a handful of lines long".)